# AngularJS Filter Object Property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

My code is outputting:

- red
- green

Using the model of `$scope.selected = '123'` how can I edit it to only output:

- red

Here's my view:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.color}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

Here's my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selected = '123';
  $scope.items = {
    '123': {
      color: 'red',
      quantity: 3
    },
    '456': {
      color: 'blue',
      quantity: 7
    }
  };
});
```

I tried using a filter with `selected` but didn't have any luck.

Comment: much better to make `items` an array, then can use filter and property in html based on predicate `selected`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing items to array:

```
 $scope.items =[ 
    {
      id:'123',
      color: 'red',
      quantity: 3
    },
     {
      id:'456',
      color: 'blue',
      quantity: 7
    }
  ];
```

You can use built in `filter` which is only available for arrays ( there was talk of object filtering also, not sure if it exists yet)

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {id:selected}">
   {{item.color}}
 </li>
```

In general it is better to work with array data that allows sorting, filtering, indexing etc much easier than with objects

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/tzjZD62mNmvDi3jKI1LG?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can create a filter for this

```
.filter('myFilter', function() {
            return function(obj, selected) {
                if (!selected) return obj;

                return {
                    value: obj[selected]
                }
            }
        }
```

here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wESQQCmhoW9qSxNZBDcU?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Filters will only work on arrays, and as charlietfl mentioned you should probably switch it to that. If you can't you can use this, though I highly recommend against it:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(key, item) in items" data-ng-if="key == selected">
           {{item.color}}     
      </li>
  </ul>
  </body>
```